# Image Encryption Using AES Algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to encrypt the content of the image so i can see it encrypted with  image viewer .

to this i tried to encrypt image pixel values , the RGB values i mean .

So all what i did is :

1- get all RGB values from image.

2- store all the RGB values into integer array

3- convert integer array into byte array for the AES input encryption.

4- get the output from the encryption and coverte into integer array.

5- set the new RGB Values from the new  integer array.

But all this hard work didnt show off , i cant see the output image because the output values from AES Algorithm is too big !!,  bigger than 255 and the RGB values must be between 0-255.

```
public class img {
        static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        static String encryptionKey = "0123456789abcdef";

static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        BufferedImage image;
        int width;
        int height;

        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\AKRAM\\Desktop\\sample.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(input);
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();

        int[] t = new int[width * height * 3];
        int k = 0;
        int kk = 0;

        // fill the table t with RGB values;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                int r = c.getRed();
                int g = c.getGreen();
                int b = c.getBlue();

                t[k] = r;
                k++;
                t[k] = g;
                k++;
                t[k] = b;
                k++;

            }
        }

        // convert table of RGB values into byte Array for the Encryption
        byte[] bb = integersToBytes(t);

        /* AES Encryption */
        byte[] cipher = encrypt(bb, encryptionKey);

        t = convertByte2Int(cipher);

        // create image with table RGB values;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                int r = t[kk];
                kk++;
                int g = t[kk];
                kk++;
                int b = t[kk];
                kk++;

                Color newColor = new Color(r, g, b);
                image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());

            }
        }
        //write the output image
        File ouptut = new File("C:\\Users\\AKRAM\\Desktop\\output.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}// end main

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
}

public static byte[] integersToBytes(int[] values) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        dos.writeInt(values[i]);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static int[] convertByte2Int(byte buf[]) {
    int intArr[] = new int[buf.length / 4];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
        intArr[i] = (buf[3 + offset] & 0xFF) | ((buf[2 + offset] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((buf[1 + offset] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((buf[0 + offset] & 0xFF) << 24);
        offset += 4;
    }
    return intArr;
  }
```

}

Comment: Why you are doing this and not read whole JPG file into byte array and Cipher it ? Also your way of storing RGB as integers and than converting to byte is awfull. Why not convert getRed() and so on into byte directly ? The returned value is according to the documentation 0-255 so you can convert this int to byte directly.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. How is supposed that you are going to see the **encrypted** image?. Data is not graphically representable

Comment: @kulatamicuda i want to encrypt the content image not the whole image , i want to see it with image viewer , about the conversation i'm beginner  to the programming world , so please take it easy for me !! THX

Comment: @pedrofb all i want is to encrypt the content of the image and i can see it with image viewer

Comment: There are only 256 unique values for an 8-bit byte, so your assumption as to why this isn't working is incorrect.  Do you get an exception?  What actually happens?  Help us to help you.

Comment: @AkramKaram And what other JPG file is than image content ? Of course it contains some other non-image content stuff but JPG file is itself much more efficient in compression than storing direct RGB pixels. So once again - why you are trying to do this instead of encrypting whole JPG ? Does it contains something you do not want to publish ? The one of the most important progarmming principle is KISS (Keep it simple stupid) and by this principle is the best way to encrypt whole file.

Comment: @LukePark nothing happen , no exception no nothing . the execution is done with no error  and also with no output image

Comment: Also, the way you convert your bytes to int and back again is incorrect.  You should simply cast the values, as you won't be working with numbers larger than 255 anyway.

Comment: @LukePark That is what I have written in my first comment ;-)

Comment: @kulatamicuda Sorry for stealing your thunder.

Comment: @LukePark maybe you can help me with that !

Comment: @LukePark no problem, you just overlooked it :-)

Comment: You should fix the problems that we have outlined and then post the updated source code.

Comment: @LukePark the conversion from int to byte and back again is correct  , i did tests about  and everything is okay ... sorry i dont know what do you mean

Comment: @AkramKaram I am not sure if you are confusing the terms 'encryption' and 'compression'. AES will encode the content so anybody without the 'encryptionKey' could get the original content, so without taking into account the conversion of `byte <-> int`, it is not possible that the ImageViewer could show the image

Comment: @pedrofb Directly encrypting only the RGB bytes will allow the image to still be displayed.  And AES is not an encoding.

Comment: @AkramKaram Yes but you aren't converting between int and byte.  E.g. not 4 bytes to 1 int.  Its 1 byte to 1 int.  So you cast.  And print your stack trace in your catch, thats why you arent getting any error output.

Comment: @LukePark i did this method byte to int                                            public static int[] byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
  IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
  int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
  intBuf.get(array);
  return array;
 }

Comment: No you didn't.  Your `int[]` is 4 times smaller than the number of RGB values that you start with.  Don't you think that might be a problem?

Comment: @LukePark, I was referring to the original image. Showing RGB encrypted  bytes i guess you will see as static in the TV

Comment: @LukePark so can you help me with that ? really not that expert in java programming

Comment: @AkramKaram The things you are trying to do is simply bad idea. The JPG file itself can have ICC profiles embedded, different color space than you expect and so on. When converting to RGB and re-creating image data only from RGB pixels you can lose a lot of meta information from JPG file itself.

Comment: @kulatamicuda yes thats true , but the problem this is a school project and my teacher want it to see the with image viewer and see random pixels that shows the algorithm is really been executed ...

Comment: YOU LOSE MANY DATA!!! aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you a bit I hope. It does not do the whole thing (we are not here to make your school homeworks) but helps you with the things you were stuck on. Compare it with your original code to understand where you made mistakes (there were more than one).

```
package kulatamicuda.aesimage.core;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 * Sample class for Stacko.
 * 
 * @author kulatamicuda
 *
 */
public final class Img {

  /**
   * RGB SIZE IS 3 (RED, GREEN, BLUE).
   */
  private static final int RGB_SIZE = 3;

  /**
   * Byte shifter for SIGNED->UNSIGNED.
   */
  private static final int BSHIFT = 0xFF;

  /**
   * Solution sample in main.
   * 
   * @param args
   *          ignored args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      BufferedImage image;
      int width;
      int height;

      File input = new File("sample.jpg");
      image = ImageIO.read(input);
      width = image.getWidth();
      height = image.getHeight();

      byte[] t = new byte[width * height * RGB_SIZE];
      int index = 0;

      // fill the table t with RGB values;
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

          Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));

          // As byte is SIGNED in Java overflow will occur for values > 127
          byte r = (byte) c.getRed();
          byte g = (byte) c.getGreen();
          byte b = (byte) c.getBlue();

          t[index++] = r;
          t[index++] = g;
          t[index++] = b;
        }
      }

      // Re-create image with table-encrypted RGB values
      BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
          BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
      index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

          // Need to deal with values < 0 so binary AND with 0xFF
          // Java 8 provides Byte.toUnsignedInt but I am from the old school ;-)
          int r = t[index++] & BSHIFT;
          int g = t[index++] & BSHIFT;
          int b = t[index++] & BSHIFT;

          Color newColor = new Color(r, g, b);
          newImage.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());

        }
      }
      // write the output image
      File output = new File("output.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", output);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: With your help the encryption and decryption was successful.thank you so much kilatamicuda .

Just one last question if you dont mind , why the size of the image changed ? i mean the original image  was 44 Ko and after the encryption and decryption the image size reduced into just 26 Ko ?? both images looks the same...

Comment: @AkramKaram Read again the last comments under your question.

Comment: Alright , by the way i totally get it  the  progarmming principle ( KISS ) :D